# Included MinionPro after every MikTeX update

Tags: fonts, miktex

Each time I update `MikTeX` packages, I have to edit `updmap.cfg`, add `Map MinionPro.map` and run `mktexlsr` and `updmap`.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: create a local texmf tree and put a small updmap.cfg with only the map line into localtexmf/miktex/config, miktex will pick that up when it runs updmap.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand the principle, but I am uncertain about application.  Accoridng to MikTeX web page, there are already local texmf trees, three of them (!) %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 (UserConfig), %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9 (UserData) and  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 (UserInstall).  I suppose I can use one of them?  Maybe I should also activate them in MikTeX console settings?

Comment: If you want to use one of them I would use UserConfig, but personally I prefer a local texmf in my documents folder, easier to find. If you use an existing tree you will have to update the file name data base (console in user mode, tasks menu) after you added the file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I created %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg and add the Map command and this seems to solved the problem.  Will you take the credit and provide a formal answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a small `updmap.cfg` with only the map line into a local texmf in `miktex/config`, miktex will pick that up when it runs updmap.

Using the existing `UserConfig`

```
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config
```

is possible too.

Don't forget to update the file name database after you added the cfg.